# The difference between in and within

Tags: prepositions, british-english

What are the differences between doing something in a period and doing something within a period?
Are there any other differences between in and Within in other contexts?

Answer (score 0):

"In" is used with expressions of time to express a period, after which something will happen - I'll see you in a week; I'll be ready in one hour (I'll see you after a week has passed; I'll be ready after one hour has passed.

> In
>
> 3Expressing the length of time before a future event is expected to
> happen.
>
> ‘I'll see you in fifteen minutes’

[In (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in)

"Within" is used to express a maximum amount of time, during which something will happen - I'll see you within a week; I'll be ready within one hour (I'll see you no later than one week in the future; I'll be ready no later than one hour in the future).

> Within
>
> 3 Occurring inside (a particular period of time)
>
> ‘tickets were sold out within two hours’ ‘33 per cent offended again
> within two years of being released’

[Within (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/within)